# Guardar Valores dos Checkboxes no Android Studio

Tags: android, checkbox, armazenamento

Estou em um projeto que tem muitos checkboxes, e eles tem que serem armazenados de modo definitivo, ou seja, quando o usuário fechar o app e reabrí-lo tem que estar marcado. Gostaria de saber como guardar os modos dos checkbox, de modo definitivo, no app criado no Android Studio? ou então transformar os Checkboxes setados em texto, pois eles não serão desmarcados nunca mais.

Aguardarei a ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode salvar no banco de dados, ou utilizar `SharedPreferences`, que acredito ser a forma mais simples:

Para facilitar, recomendo cria uma classe que contenha os valores que queria salvar:

```
class Valores
{
    boolean check1;
    boolean check2;
    boolean check3;
    boolean check4;
}
```

Método para salvar esta classe:

```
   /**
     * seta os valores no SharedPreferences
     * @param valores
     */
    public void setValores(Valores valores)
    {
        // passamos o nome do objeto que vamos criar e o modo de armazenamento
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("VALORES_TELA_UM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // setamos o nome da propriedade e o valor
        editor.putBoolean("CHECK1", valores.check1);
        editor.putBoolean("CHECK2", valores.check2);
        editor.putBoolean("CHECK3", valores.check3);
        editor.putBoolean("CHECK4", valores.check4);
        // commitando as alteracoes
        editor.commit();

    }
```

Método para resgatar os valores:

```
  public Valores getValores()
    {
        Valores valores = new Valores();

        final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("VALORES_TELA_UM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        valores.check1 = prefs.getBoolean("CHECK1", false);
        valores.check2 = prefs.getBoolean("CHECK2", false);
        valores.check3 = prefs.getBoolean("CHECK3", false);
        valores.check4 = prefs.getBoolean("CHECK4", false);

        return valores;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A api do Android tem maneiras de você salvar as preferências da sua app como conjuntos chave/valor(key/value). Confira a documentação [Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

**Para criar o arquivo de preferências(no caso qual checkbox marcada):**

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Aonde `R.string.preference_file_key` é uma string que você declara com o nome do arquivo que conterá os conjuntos chave/valor.

**Para salvar um conjunto chave valor:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.show_score), true);
editor.commit();
```

Aonde `R.string.show_score` é uma string com o nome da sua chave, que no seu caso poderia ser `chkRodaEmModoNavio`.

**Para ler suas preferências:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean defaultValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.string.show_score_default);
boolean showHighScore = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.show_score), defaultValue);
```